# How to use Matlab toolboxes consist of .p suffix?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have Matlab toolbox contains files with .p suffix.

I've set path it but when I've run main files of toolbox this error appeared :

**p was generated prior to MATLAB version 7.5 (R2007b) and is
no longer supported.  Use pcode to regenerate the file using MATLAB R2007b or later.**

Is there any way to use this toolbox for newer versions of matlab like 2011 or newer?

Comment: You have to ask the author to regenerate the file using MATLAB R2007b or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A p-code file is an obfuscated version of an m-file that should not be readable by the recipient; however, MATLAB is still able to read and interpret these files as though they were the original (unobfuscated) m-files.

As the error states, an older version of MATLAB was used to generate the p-code files you have and therefore it may not be compatible with the version of MATLAB that you are using.

You would need to get a copy of the original m-files as there is no reliable way to "recompile" a p-code file. You would need to run [`pcode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html) on the original m-files to generate new/compatible p-files.

This may require that you get in touch with the original developer.

That being said, it should just be a warning and you should be able to still use the files with the caveat that there may be unexpected behavior.